# The process cannot access the file 'C:Project\App_Data\Database.mdf' because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#

I'm getting the following error:

> The process cannot access the file
>   'C:Project\App_Data\Database.mdf'
>   because it is being used by another
>   process.

How can I solve it?

Comment: That's usually because the `.mdf` file should be attached. If you don't find which process is using it, restart the SQL Server service.

Comment: Everyone is asuming it's a SQL Server database file but there's actually an disk image format with the same extension out there and this question doesn't say which, it just came with the C# tag but I see no C# code or C# related question... Moreover the Resource Monitor in the task manager has the functionality of listing all open files handles and which file and process involved. That' two answers two this question that where quicky trashed and disregarded despite being perfectly valid. Give it some time at least and let's see if user596379 ever rerturns with more info...

Answer (score 0):

It's used by another process, maybe from SQL Server service.
You could use [Unlocker](http://www.filehippo.com/download_unlocker/) to find which process and take appropriate action.
Be careful: if'you re using VS, you could have opened a db connection during development.

Comment: This error is when I am trying to publish the website and my database is open so the error came out but howevere if i were to close the database and publish the website.The website could be able to publish but the data in the database could be be read.

Comment: @user596379: if I remember well (correct me if I'm wrong, please) when you publish the website, VS first deletes all files in destination dir... and that's the big deal because your DB is opened and it cannot be deleted. Try (don't know if it's possible) to tell VS not to delete what it finds in dest dir, but just update older files...

Comment: @user596379: if I understand well, yours is a production pc, so you cannot stop database, but you just need to update web. Well, not a good answer, but just an idea: publish web site in another dir and then, manually or with a script, update production environment.. but I don't know if IIS complains or if its cache can give you some trouble.